# I am getting an segmentation fault error in line head=NULL

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I didn't understand why i am getting error in line head=NULL I am just pointing head towards NULL

I have also tried creating a new node for head and then pointing towards NULL but still it doesn't work

**Code show here**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
struct node
{
  int data;
  node *next;
};

 node *head=NULL;
 node *tail=NULL;


 void createnode(int value)
  {
  node *temp=new node;
  temp->data=value;
  temp->next=NULL;
  if(head==NULL)
  {
    head=temp;
    tail=temp;
    temp=NULL;
  }
  else
  { 
    tail->next=temp;
    tail=temp;
  }
}
void deletek(int n,int k)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    return;
    node *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp->data<temp->next->data)
    {
        head=temp->next;
        temp=temp->next;
        k--;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL&&k!=0)
    {
        if(temp->next->data<temp->next->next->data)
        {
            temp->next=temp->next->next;
            k--;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void display()
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;

}

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
int n,k;

for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    cin>>n>>k;
    int arr[n];

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin>>arr[j];
        createnode(arr[j]);
    }
    deletek(n,k);

    display();
    head=NULL;


}

}
```

I expect that whenever the line head=NULL runs the previous linked list should get delete and I should be able to enter elements in the linked list from the beginning

Comment: What error? Compile time? Runtime? Also give an exact example of input.

Comment: How are you determining that that particular line is the cause? It's extremely unlikely, unless your compiler is faulty. `deletek`, on the other hand, has bugs.

Comment: I am surprised this code even compiles, since you are using the non const integer n to initialize arr (in main), which is invalid. What is the compiler you are using?

Comment: Also `stdc++.h`, guessing GCC, as I think both are commonly available there.

Comment: I know the line head=NULL is the cause because if I remove this line this code works perfectly fine but the elements keeps on inserting in the existing linked list instead of creating a new one

Comment: @HarshitMittal If it fails if you add a random line, it doesn't mean that it fails **on** such line. Did you step through your code with a debugger, while investigating values of the variables, along the way?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes I have debugged this code and this code works upto my expectations without the line head=NULL

Comment: @HarshitMittal What console input (numbers?) gives the crash?

Comment: @HarshitMittal Why didn't you debug it, in the case where it crashes, then, if you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: @FireLancer the error is not dependent on inputs it is crashing in every case as it is saying I can't set head to NULL in this way

Comment: Always check for null before accessing the data. In your code I see you are checking null only for temp. You mush check null for temp ->next and temp->next->next.

Comment: @HarshitMittal - "I expect that whenever the line head=NULL runs the previous linked list should get delete and I should be able to enter elements in the linked list from the beginning" - I am yet to debug your code, but please understand first that your expectation is totally wrong. Infact you will end up with memory leaks. In C/C++ you need to deallocate all memory that you create on the heap. Although this would have worked in Java as the list would get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: C++ likes "nullptr" (since C++11) for this, instead of "NULL".

=> e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL vs. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr 
Second: The exact compiler output could help.

 Third: The list will not be deleted if you throw away the address of it's location. maybe you should rather create a class and/or add destructor for your node. If you want to implement LL by yourself
Or have a look at std::list -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list. I use this rather often. 
Or if you like to add boost dependency: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html more fancy but you'll add an external library 
**Then**: The Segfault (on my PC) happens in   if(temp->next->datanext->next->data) I guess you can never know if temp->next->next->data exists... maybe not even if temp->next->data => if temp->next points to NULL (or nullptr) it is not a valid instance of node to dereference
try: 
`

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #define HERE() printf("HERE: %d\n", __LINE__)
    using namespace std;
    struct node
    {
      int data;
      node *next;
    };

     node *head=NULL;
     node *tail=NULL;


     void createnode(int value)
      {
      node *temp=new node;
      temp->data=value;
  temp->next=NULL;
  if(head==NULL)
  {
    head=temp;
    tail=temp;
    temp=NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    tail->next=temp;
    tail=temp;
  }
}
void deletek(int n,int k)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    return;
    node *temp;
    temp=head;

    while(temp->data<temp->next->data)
    {
        head=temp->next;
        temp=temp->next;
        k--;
    }
HERE();
    while(temp!=NULL&&k!=0)
    {
HERE();
int d1 = temp->next->data;
HERE();
int d2 = temp->next->next->data;
        if(temp->next->data < temp->next->next->data)
        {
            temp->next=temp->next->next;
            k--;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void display()
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;

}

int main() {
int t;
cout << "input t:" << endl;
cin>>t;
int n,k;

for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
        cout << "input n/k" << endl;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int arr[n];

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout << "input arr[" << j <<"]" << endl;
        cin>>arr[j];
        createnode(arr[j]);
    }
    deletek(n,k);

    display();
    head=NULL;


}

}
```

`